# WSUS Command to decline updates

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to force my WSUS to decline updates through a command line because it is overloaded i cannot access the mangement snap in. This is a code that i found online but the only problem i am having is that my server has dashes in the name and is messing up the code. I tried placing qoutations around the name and it still spits back an invalid character after ":" from 3rd line

EDIT: New Error
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.CreateUpdateServer(Object[] args) at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.GetupdateServer(String serverName, Boolean useSecureConnection, Int32 portnumber) at Callsite.Target(Closure , Callsite , Type , Object , Object , Object )

```
#Change server name and port number and $True if it is on SSL

$Computer = $env:common-n-sccm2012
$Domain = $env:airplane.black.low.com
$FQDN = "$Computer" + "." + "$Domain"
[String]$updateServer1 = $FQDN
[Boolean]$useSecureConnection = $False
[Int32]$portNumber = 8530

# Load .NET assembly

[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")

$count = 0

# Connect to WSUS Server

$updateServer = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($updateServer1,$useSecureConnection,$portNumber)

write-host "<<<Connected sucessfully >>>" -foregroundcolor "yellow"

$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope

$u=$updateServer.GetUpdates($updatescope )

foreach ($u1 in $u )

{

if ($u1.IsSuperseded -eq 'True')

{

write-host Decline Update : $u1.Title

$u1.Decline()

$count=$count + 1

}

}

write-host Total Declined Updates: $count

trap

{

write-host "Error Occurred"

write-host "Exception Message: "

write-host $_.Exception.Message

write-host $_.Exception.StackTrace

exit

}

# EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the error pops up at this line:

```
$Computer = $env:common-n-sccm2012
```

because you are trying to get an environment variable with dashes in its name. You may try to format it as:

```
$Computer = ${env:common-n-sccm2012}
```

**HOWEVER**

I think you are 'Environmentifying' hardcoded values and that is the actual problem.

It is hard to believe that you do in fact have Environment variables with names like `common-n-sccm2012` and `airplane.black.low.com`.

To get the actual Fully Qualified Domain Name from the computer you are on, you could do this:

```
$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME          # --> "common-n-sccm2012"
$Domain   = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN         # --> "airplane.black.low.com"
$FQDN = "$Computer" + "." + "$Domain"  # --> "common-n-sccm2012.airplane.black.low.com"
```

( or in one line: `$FQDN = "$env:COMPUTERNAME.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"` )

You can also obtain this FQDN using WMI:

```
$FQDN = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).DNSHostName + "." + (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
```

You can read about Environment Variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Yes that worked! I was trying with the $ in side the brackets so it wasn't working thank you. I am now recieving another error now. 

Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
 at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.CreateUpdateServer(Object[] args)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.GetupdateServer(String serverName, Boolean useSecureConnection, Int32 portnumber)
at Callsite.Target(Closure , Callsite , Type , Object , Object , Object )

Comment: This issue may be about permissions of the user that you used? Are you running the PowerShell ISE as Administrator?

Comment: I am logged in as an Admin and ran PowerShell ISE as administrator too. should i be logged in as a local admin and not a domain admin?

Comment: I got the same error when i was logged in as my local admin too

Comment: @SidGuidry I have added stuff to my answer to hopefully make it clear where the actual problem lies.